# Calling distinct test func in TestMain() in Golang

Tags: testing, go

I'm trying to test my http controllers and I use TestMain func to prepare my testing, but before I run all test requests I need to first run `TestAuthUserController` test, which creates and authorizes the user. For this I use wrapper func, which helps me to call `TestAuthUserController`:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M)  {
    //some prepearing steps
    AuthUserController()//create and authorize user before all other tests
    m.Run()
    fmt.Println("after all in main")
    dbMdm.End()
}

    //AuthUserController is a wrapper func to run TestAuthUserController before all other tests in TestMain func
func AuthUserController() func(t *testing.T){
    fmt.Println("in wrapper")
    return TestAuthUserController
}
```

this is my `TestAuthUserController`:

```
//TestAuthUserController tests in series creation of new user and his authorization
func TestAuthUserController(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize", testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize)
    t.Run("testAuthorizeUserSuccess", testAuthorizeUserSuccess)
}
```

when I run command `go test` - it's ok! the TestMain call it successfuly,
But when I'm trying to run some test separately, for example `go test -run TestSomeController` it failed, because of `TestAuthUserController` doesn't runs in this case.

Comment: You are asking the go tool to run TestSomeController only and are now wondering why TestAuthUserController doesn't run? You are getting exactly what you ordered.

Comment: Don't use `TestMain`. Just have each test instead call the setup function directly.

Comment: @Peter, I ask to run TestSomeController, but my TestAuthUserController must be called in TestMain(m *testing.M), and TestMain is run in all cases...

Comment: If TestAuthUserController isn't a test, but rather some setup code, don't make it look like a test.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
func setupTestUserAndAuthorise(){
   // create user, authorise

   // return User
}

func deleteTestUser(user User){
   // delete user and other clean up actions
}

func TestCase1(t *testing.T){
    user := setupUserAndAuthorise()
    defer deleteTestUser(user)

    // use this user in test
}
```

You can create a function that creates a new user, authorises and returns it.
After the test runs, you can call a cleanup function that deletes user etc.

The order of execution of unit tests should not affect the outcome of tests.

Answer (score 0):

I've created main.go file and main_test.go for test file. In main_test.go file it contains below code:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.T)  {
    fmt.Println("Testing is running...")
    AuthUserController()
}

func AuthUserController() func(t *testing.T){
    fmt.Println("in wrapper")
    return TestAuthUserController
}


func testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize(m *testing.T)  {
    fmt.Println("create user... testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize")
}

func testAuthorizeUserSuccess(m *testing.T)  {
    fmt.Println("authorize user... testAuthorizeUserSuccess")
}

func TestAuthUserController(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize", testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize)
    t.Run("testAuthorizeUserSuccess", testAuthorizeUserSuccess)
}
```

When you run this command: **go test -run TestAuthUserController**

```
//Here is the output:
Testing is running... testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize
Testing is running... testAuthorizeUserSuccess
PASS
```

Hope that this is what your expected. :)

Comment: in my tests this case works too. But if you will  add any other unit test and run it in the same order, then `TestAuthUserController` will be not called...

Comment: I added **TestSomeController(t *testing.T)** in main_test.go file and run  **go test -run TestSomeController** it works also..

Comment: I created also name_test.go and put **TestSomeController(m *testing.T)** with **TestAnotherMain(m *testing.T)** and it works also. take note that if you add another unit test(test file) you must add suffix "_test".

Comment: your `func TestMain(m *testing.T)` accept testing.T pointer  in place of testing.M. I tried your example. But when I run `go test -run TestAuthUserController` I have this output: `create user... testCreateUserSuccessBeforeAuthorize
authorize user... testAuthorizeUserSuccess
` It seems programm doesn't call `TestMain`

Comment: If you want to call TestMain, you can put TestMain inside your ** TestAuthUserController** like this **t.Run("testMain()", TestMain)** and run it again go test -run TestAuthUserController

Comment: I have a lot of controllers and tests for them (in different files) and I want to be able to run them either all together or each separately. But in any case, `TestAuthUserController` should be called first. if I put TestMain to my **TestAuthUserController** and apply `t.Run`, I will be not able do this, because if I run  `go test -run TestAuthUserController` it's ok, and if I run `go test -run TestSomeController` it's not.

Comment: please see my screenshot above

Comment: TestMain runs in main goroutine. so it is impossible to call without using r.Run in your test method (TestAuthUserController).